# Implementing Math.pow() in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, pow

I cant find any pre defined function in blackberry JDE to implement Math.pow(). Can anyone please suggest how to power the values that are retrieved from the Edit text fields(Like X^Y value)...

Comment: Is `Y` an integer or a floating point number in your case?

Comment: Can't you do the alternative, looping yourself as many times as the power and just re-multiplying the value by itself?

Comment: @Luke it becomes harder when Y is a real number. It may or may not be the case here.

Comment: float fSecondFactor=(float) (Math.(1+fRatePerMonth,fNumberofMonths)-1);

This is what i have to achieve....

Comment: @Luke The user enter the number of months. So, it wont be a good idea to run a loop say 36 times if the user enter number of months to be 36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `net.rim.device.api.util.MathUtilities.pow ( double double )`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement your own.  Check out

```
net.rim.device.api.util.MathUtilities.pow ( double double )
```

Comment: Can u tell me how to implement this???

float fSecondFactor=(float) (Math.pow(1+fRatePerMonth,fNumberofMonths)-1);

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, i also came across this limitation at one point- (keeping a single library to be used in both j2me AND blackBerry) and there's a decent discussion at http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/06/creating-java-me-math-pow-method.html which should help you. i've used this code and it's worked for me